# How to access jsp pages placed under WebApp/jsp parallel to WEB-INF

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web, jboss

I am migrating one web project from weblogic to Jboss. I have jsp pages under WebApp/jsp and tlds under WebApp/tlds parallel to WEB-INF. When i am hitting my url, it calls my Servlet filter which redirect it to Welcome page.

WebApp --->WEB-INF\web.xml

```
   --->jsp

   --->tlds
```

My problem is that redirect is not working. its looking for Welcome page under ProjectFolder while it is available under ProjectFolder/jsp.

is there any way through that i can tell my app that jsp's are under /jsp folder instead of root folder.

**UPDATE**
web.xml snippet used for init param

```
<init-param>
     <param-name>dispatchPage</param-name>
     <param-value>/viewReport.jsp</param-value>
</init-param>
```

And the java code that actual does redirect:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
   getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(getInitParameter("dispatchPage"));
dispatcher.forward(req,res)
```

Comment: What is the piece of code in servlet filter that is redirecting to welcome page?  If you can share, someone can point out potential issue

Comment: <init-param>
  <param-name>dispatchPage</param-name>
  <param-value>/viewReport.jsp</param-value>
 </init-param> and code is as below                            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(getInitParameter("dispatchPage"));
   dispatcher.forward(req,res);

Comment: Please add it to main question

Comment: if i change my web.xml as below, it works for me but i don't have to change it. <init-param> <param-name>dispatchPage</param-name> <param-value>/jsp/viewReport.jsp</param-value> </init-param>

Comment: <param-value>/jsp/viewReport.jsp</param-value> is the right way as far as I know.  JSPs are always looked relative to webapp folder

Comment: Yes but it has been used in same way at lot more place and i can't update it everywhere. in case if i do for java then i have a challenge for tlds/. well in case of tld, its relative path but still its not picking it.